# Transmission Control Protocol socket

Tags: sockets, tcp

When I open TCP with the server (on 7 layer of OSI), the layer 5 create socket with port number and IP.
I want to know if this socket include my IP/the server IP, and my (random) port or the server port (e.g. 80 for HTTP)

And when I open TCP with server we open TCP together
So it's mean we have common socket?

Answer (score 0):

> When I open TCP with the server (on 7 layer of OSI)

Forget about OSI. It is obsolete, and TCP/IP doesn't follow it. It has its own layer model.

> The layer 5 create socket with port number and IP

TCP creates it at the TCP layer.

> I want to know if this socket include my IP/the server IP, and my (random) port or the server port (80 for HTTP for ex.)

All of the above.

> And when I open TCP with server we open TCP together So it's mean we have common socket?

No. A socket is an endpoint of a connection. There are two ends, and two sockets.

Comment: So the socket have my port,his port,my ip,his ip?  And why there are 2 socket?  Thanks

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Because there are two ends to the connection.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a Layer 4 as it is called - or a Transport Layer, so ignore the OSI model for the time being.

Generally - 'a socket' is just an end point without any identity. The socket gets it's identity when you `bind` to an address or `connect` to an address.

When you `bind` to an address - you only get your local port and local IP address in it's end point, but not the remote IP and port address. As such such socket is not very useful unless you `listen` on it. This is typically done on the server. Also note that you can bind to 'All Addresses on the machine' and then you really don't have any one end-point per se.

When you `connect` to a server (a TCP server @ port 80 say), your OS TCP/IP stack makes use of a local IP address and chooses a random port to connect to a sever socket (like say one `listen`ing above). This is when all the 4 addresses come into picture. This socket is a connected socket and all 4 values will be present.

Comment: You do have 'any one endpoint'. You don't 'bind to all addresses on the machine': you bind to a special address that means *any*. Not 'all'. It makes a difference.

Comment: I not totally inderstanding-   So yhe server build he socket with his port and his ip? Why not with my port and my ip?

Comment: How would server know your port and your IP? I suggest you read "TCP/IP Illustrated Volume 1" before you venture into socket programming.

Comment: @chriswhite The server *doesn't* know the client's IP:port, until he connects. Then he knows it from the IP packets.